# Как отловить тап на смартфоне?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Хочу реализовать прыжок по **двойному нажатию** в определенной области. Как считать первое и следующие нажатие по экрану чтобы проверить что было нажата **"двойным тапом"**?

По некоторым урокам я достиг этого в **движке**, но на устройстве это работать не будет, потому что я проверяю нажатие одной кнопки, но не **тача**. Находил решения, но они не дали мне понять как это работает, и в целом я хотел бы получить ответ на свой случай.

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Left && eventData.clickCount == 2)
    {
        player_.GetComponent<Player_Controller>().Jump(); // Функция прыжка

        IsButtonPressed = true; // Кнопка нажалась
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UI API (не путать с input system) в Unity поддерживает и мышь, и тачи.](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData.html)

`PointerEventData.InputButton.Left` и вообще весь enum `PointerEventData.InputButton` - это чисто мышь, я не уверен, что такое даже соберется под смартфоны.

Для тачей достаточно условия `if(eventData.clickCount > 0)`, чтобы понять, что тап по IPointClickHandler'у был, проверять "область" срабатывания тоже не нужно, данный интерфейс получит такое событие только если нажали именно на него.